# Defined Template from logstash not being used by elastic search for mapping

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following logstash output config to go into elasticsearch from a postgres database

https://pastebin.com/BFCH3tuZ

I have defined the location and my template as the following:

https://pastebin.com/mK5qshKM

When I run logstash I see the output as follows:

```
[2017-05-24T20:54:10,828][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-05-24T20:54:10,982][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>#<URI::HTTP:0xff97ab URL:http://localhost:9200/>}
[2017-05-24T20:54:10,985][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>"/etc/logstash/universe_template.json"}
[2017-05-24T20:54:11,045][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"universe_elastic", "settings"=>{"analysis"=>{"filter"=>{"gr$
[2017-05-24T20:54:11,052][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Installing elasticsearch template to _template/universe_elastic
[2017-05-24T20:54:11,145][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>[#<URI::Generic:0xe60519 URL://localhost:9200$
[2017-05-24T20:54:11,154][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inf$
[2017-05-24T20:54:11,988][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-05-24T20:54:12,079][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-05-24T20:54:12,108][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.101000s) select planet.id, planet.x || ':' || planet.y || ':' || planet.z coords, planet.x, planet.y, planet.z ,planetname,ru$
[2017-05-24T20:54:15,006][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

When I query elasticseach templates I can see my template listed at:

```
http://xxxx:9200/_template/ {   "universe_elastic": {
    "order": 0,
    "template": "universe_elastic",
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "gramFilter": {
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "punctuation",
                "symbol"
              ], ETC ETC ETC......
```

However when I run a check on my "universe" index the mapping haven't come through:

https://pastebin.com/hw9hYfLn

I would expect to see the _all field and the include in all references set to true/false. But nothing.. Also the queries do not then use the analyzers I have specified.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here? I have deleted out all the other possible templates created as well as re-created indexes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done it almost all correctly, you just need to change a single thing:

In your template, this line

```
  "template": "universe_elastic",
```

should read

```
  "template": "universe",
```

ES is going to apply the apply only if your index name matches with the template name.

Comment: Damn! I even knew that too but I think staring at the code for so long caused me to blank on that one. Thanks for the diligence!

Comment: Does this also work if index name has some date parts, like universe-2017.05.25? Can I just set this in the template: "template": "universe-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}",